# Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute tests using JENKINS.
Chrome Browser is getting opened but nothing is happening on the browser.
am observing the below error's on JENKIN's console

Can someone please help me with this:

```
[101208:121084:0919/123709.490:ERROR:install_util.cc(603)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[101208:121084:0919/123709.490:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[101208:121084:0919/123709.490:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[101208:121084:0919/123709.490:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: DnsPrefetchingEnabled
[101208:121084:0919/123709.490:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken
[101208:121084:0919/123709.490:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: RemoteAccessHostRequireTwoFactor
[101208:121084:0919/123709.490:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: SiginAllowed
[101208:121084:0919/123709.522:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: AlwaysAuthorizePlugins
[101208:121084:0919/123709.522:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: DisablePluginFinder
[101208:121084:0919/123709.522:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: DnsPrefetchingEnabled
[101208:121084:0919/123709.522:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken
[101208:121084:0919/123709.522:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: RemoteAccessHostRequireTwoFactor
[101208:121084:0919/123709.522:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(91)] Unknown policy: SiginAllowed

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12389/devtools/browser/4c685c14-13f6-47d2-9930-bd3d69f6cf8b
Sep 19, 2018 12:37:46 PM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: AutoTest_Workspace #49 main build action completed: FAILURE
```

I already tried the below solution:

[image]

But did not find any Luck.

Comment: It works fine when I added the string `MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken` using `regedit` in this path Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Some more information about the usecase in terms of:

- *Selenium Client* version
- *ChromeDriver* version
- *Chrome Browser* version

Would have helped us to construct a canonical answer. However,

- As per [[14452:3972:0531/170507.354:ERROR:install_util.cc(597)] Unable to read registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken for writing result=2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=848232) it wasn't an error that will block *Chrome* usage but still this had been fixed through the commit [Logging tweaks for enrollment token retrieval](http://crrev.com/eb49ccc013d304921d419249b955a0bf03905ca6)
- This is fixed in *chrome v68.0.3433.0* or later.

---

### Solution

As you have already tried the solution from 
[[14596:10928:0531/174034.867:ERROR:install_util.cc(589)] Unable to create registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome for reading result=2 [14452:3972:0531/170507.354:ERROR:install_util.cc(597)] Unable to read registry value HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken for writing result=2](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5966) which didn't work and is as follows:

[image: Registry_Key]

- Ensure Chromium/Google Chrome is installed in a recognized location.

  - ChromeDriver expects you to have Chrome installed in the default location for your platform.

[image: ChromeLocation]

- You can also force ChromeDriver to use a custom location by setting a special capability.

[image: ChromeDifferentLocation]

---

### Additional Consideration

Additionally you need to ensure the following:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.42**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v68-70*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.42 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB I tried writing a new string on the Registry under SOFTWARE/Policies/Chrome but I was not able to... it said "Error Writing to reistry"

Comment: @Malky.Kid Ensure that you have the required rights to change the registry and further try cleaning up your system through [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner)