# How to hide the ChromeDriver error "Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken:"?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm executing a Selenium script written in Python with ChromeDriver 2.43 in Windows 10

**Here is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chromedriver_path="C:\\Users\\user1\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver_path
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\user1\scripts>python test.py
[5632:15724:1114/172253.045:ERROR:install_util.cc(691)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56320/devtools/browser/83af4222-f6f2-47ea-939c-f9818c5ff3c5
```

How to hide this error in output?

Comment: Check this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401561/failed-to-read-hklm-software-policies-google-chrome-machinelevelusercloudpolicye

Comment: I'm using chrome browser Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: In Python, using `try, except` can we suppress/hide the error message ?

Comment: I don't feel you can proceed with this exception. Go through the discussion which covers three different approach for the solution. Perhaps there wasn't a canonical solution available. Different solution worked for different usecases.

Comment: It works fine when I added the string `MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken' using `regedit`  in this path Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome

Comment: That error message with `Failed to read` was removed after editing the registry.

Comment: But how to remove the message `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58802/devtools/browser/df52e552-e301-499a-84ed-21d0553ba46e`  ?

Comment: This question was related to this error only, right? If your requirement have changed feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.